# How common is it to use the lily flower/yuri 百合 to represent girls' love in Japanese anime?

Tags: meaning, anime

So I've seen some say that using lilies is very common for an author to show that a girl is lesbian for example.

However, I've heard that the whole lilies = lesbian thing is not mainstream. So I was wondering, how common is this trope used really outside of the yuri genre?

Comment: Related off-site discussion: https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1840155

Comment: @Rubiksmoose not sure how true that is

Comment: How true what is? It's a discussion related to your question. I'm not claiming any of it is true.

Comment: This question also seems a lot more appropriate for https://anime.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not pertinent to the Japanese language.

Answer (score 2):

百合 is a very common term, and virtually every anime/manga fan knows its association with female-female relationships. It's hard to imagine an otaku who does not understand the meaning of [YuruYuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuruYuri), for example.

However, you have to understand the following points (I [explained](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104949/discussion-between-zain-alleck-and-naruto) some of them to you before):

- Outside the otaku culture, indeed it's not mainstream at all. Today, 百合 mainly refers to female-female romance **in fiction**. Wikipedia defines this as follows.

  > Yuri (百合, "lily"), (snip) is a Japanese jargon term for content and a genre involving lesbian relationships or female homoeroticism **in light novels, manga, anime, video games and related Japanese media**.

  If you want to know words for lesbian used outside otaku contexts, see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41714/5010).
- 百合 is the name of a very common flower, too. Even in the otaku culture, it can simply refer to a flower with absolutely no sexual implication. As I explained before, "banana" has a sexual connotation even in English, but that does not mean it is used in a sexual sense whenever you see it in a novel.
- As an aside, if you know the term [*yaoi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi), this word fell out of use long ago in Japanese. Young Japanese otaku may not even know this word. (Today, 腐 (ふ; slangy) and BL (sounds relatively "formal") are the common terms.)

Comment: is there a term that is used instead of yaoi now?

Comment: @katatahito Please see the edit.

Comment: @naruto Thanks to clarify, I mean is it more common for the flower to be used to represent lesbianism in anime/manga or have other meanings like just simply being a flower. I.E, someone in anime likes lilies but isn't lesbian.

Comment: @zainalleck I don't know such statistics, but contexts and the knowledge of each work are *far* more important. Usually the meaning is self-evident if you know Japanese well enough.

Comment: I see,but in your view/case, how does it seem based on your experiences?

Comment: @ZainAlleck As I said many times, both usages are very common and natural. *My* experience is not important because it depends on what kind of reader *I* am. That said, when someone says 百合**の花** ("lily **flower**") verbosely in manga, it probably means he wanted to avoid the slangy meaning of 百合. [This entry](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E7%99%BE%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E8%8A%B1) also says 百合**の花** is a phrase that is used to specifically refer to the flower itself when there is a chance of misunderstanding.

Comment: @naruto sorry I'd like  to clarify a few things. I meant, specifically  like in anime/manga is it  also very common to use the flower to mean something outside of the slang yuri. Also, to refer to the flower, can you just write 百合 as it is then?

Comment: @naruto if you don't mind me asking, could you answer my last two questions to clarify

Comment: @ZainAlleck Please, read my answer and comments before asking. I have answered your questions many times.